# How do I split a value using the split function from javascript to split checking only the first and last occurence

Tags: javascript, regex

So I need to split an regex that's coming from my database. The value is like the following

```
regexValue = '/^([0-9]{3}\.?[0-9]{3}\.?[0-9]{3}\-?[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{2}\.?[0-9]{3}\.?[0-9]{3}\/?[0-9]{4}\-?[0-9]{2})$/ig'
```

if you analyze throughly this regex you can see that it have an forward slash '/' between the regex. So if I wanted to split it, using

```
values.split('/');
```

It would generate more strings than I would like to. For example a simple regex

```
//would generate three values("", \w+ , ig)    
regexValue = '/\w+/ig'
regexValue.split('/');
```

Is there a way so I could only split getting the first and last values?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder > coming from my database.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder was quoting the first sentence, thought block comments with > work in comments.

Comment: @DownloadPizza - ***Doh!*** My eyes are really dodgy toward the end of the day, thanks. FWIW, when I do that I just use quotes: "coming from my database" Or sometimes italicized quotes: *"coming from my database"*. For max clarity, I might start with saying who I'm quoting. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to split that string into the regular expression bodyand its flags, you can do that easily with...a regular expression.

```
const parts = /^\s*\/(.*)\/(?:([a-z]*))\s*$/.exec(regexString);
//           A ^
//           B  ^^^
//           C     ^^
//           D       ^^^^
//           E           ^^
//           F             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
//           G                         ^^^
//           H                            ^
```

- A: Start of input
- B: Optional whitespace
- C: Leading slash of regex "literal"
- D: Body of the expression
- E: Ending slash of regex "literal"
- F: Optional flags
- G: Optional whitespace
- H: End of input

Live Example:

```js
const regexString = '/^([0-9]{3}\\.?[0-9]{3}\\.?[0-9]{3}\\-?[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{2}\\.?[0-9]{3}\\.?[0-9]{3}\\/?[0-9]{4}\\-?[0-9]{2})$/ig';

const parts = /^\s*\/(.*)\/(?:([a-z]*))\s*$/.exec(regexString);
if (!parts) {
    console.log("No match");
} else {
    const [, body, flags] = parts;
    console.log(`body:  ${body}`);
    console.log(`flags: ${flags}`);
}
```

---

Note that I escaped the backslashes in the string literal, since you said you're reading this from your database, you don't have it in a string literal in your code. It's just that inside a string literal, a backslash is an escape character, so `\.` and `.` mean exactly the same thing. To write a string literal defining a string with backslashes in it, you have to escape them as I've done in the snippet above. Again, you've said it comes from your database, so you're fine, but I figured I should escape them in the example to avoid being misleading.

Comment: Thanks! I am now testing it and so far I have encountered no problems. this adjustment will improve my code. 

I am really grateful for your help, have a nice day !